# Result of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$

Tags: power-series, uniform-convergence

I already showed that $\displaystyle g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$ converges uniformly on $[\delta,2\pi-\delta ]$ for $\delta>0$

Now I have to calculate the limit of $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n*exp(int)}{n}$ for $t\in (0,2\pi)$

For $\displaystyle f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{exp(int)}{n}$ I showed convergence, so I guess $\displaystyle F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{exp(int)}{n}x^n$ converges for $x=1$.
Is this enough to say that that $f(t)$ is the limit of $F(x)$ as $x\to1^-$?

I would continue with Abel's theorem that $F(x)$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Here is where I don't make any progress. I should calculate the result of $F(x)$ and then conclude to the result of $g(x)$. I guess that the imaginary part will be $g(x)$.

Are my thoughts right? How can I calculate the result? Any hints?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions therefore the sum is about $ \frac{\pi}{2}- frac{x}{2\pi} $

Comment: @JoseGarcia i have to do i this way, so no shortcut

Answer (score 0):

$f(t)$ does **not** converge uniformly on $[0, 2\pi]$! At $t=0$ and $x\nearrow 1$ you have $F(x) = \infty$, thus $F$ cannot be continuous on $[0,1]$

Comment: but $t\in(0,2\pi)$ and sorry i meant $f(t)$ converges (not uniformly)